# Find an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ so that $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Find an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ so that $A=PDP^{−1}$. Use your answer to find an expression for A$^6$ in terms of $P$, a power of $D$, and $P−1$ in that order.

[link to question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZRrF.png)

Comment: You need to show us your working if you want us to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Eigenvalues will give you the matrix D, vectors P.
Then the rest should come easy.
Good luck on your test...